# Certain Characters Deleted When Submitted Through POST

Tags: php, html

I have two issues

1. When I submit the character `'` through my HTML form (using POST) it is fine. However, in the form I allow to modify the submitted content, when it is brought in, anything after the `'` disappears. I've deduced that this is because when I assign the text content containing the `'` to the text field, it closes the quote. For example, if I submit Hello there I'm John, it will do: `<input type=text value='Hello there I'm Jon />`
   So you see, the apostrophe in `I'm` closes the quote for the value attribute. So the only solution I can think of would be to escape the apostrophe, but even when I leave my mysql_real_escape_string() function on the content (as it's submitted to a database escaped and retrieved for this form).
2. Similarly, when I submit an `&` or a `+`, it disappears. This happens any time I try to print it anywhere, regardless of using the `htmlspecialchars()` function (which I was under the impression should encode them in HTML format for such characters, like: `&amp;`). so as an example, if someone enters `Me & you` then it will be displayed as `Me  you`.

So I'm asking: How can I fix the above issues, seeming to have to do with special characters, despite already having them escaped (and I even tried applying the escape function again)? If there is any sample code I should supply, please let me know, but I've explained what I am doing to each input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I submit the character `'` through my HTML form (using POST) it is fine. However, in the form I allow to modify the submitted content, when it is brought in, anything after the ' disappears. I've deduced that this is because when I assign the text content containing the ' to the text field, it closes the quote. For example, if I submit Hello there I'm John, it will do: `<input type=text value='Hello there I'm Jon />` So you see, the apostrophe in I'm closes the quote for the value attribute. So the only solution I can think of would be to escape the apostrophe, but even when I leave my `mysql_real_escape_string()` function on the content (as it's submitted to a database escaped and retrieved for this form).

This has nothing to do with submitting the data. You are trying to use `'` in an attribute value that is delimited with `'` characters.

Use [`htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES)`](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

> Similarly, when I submit an & or a +, it disappears. This happens any time I try to print it anywhere, regardless of using the htmlspecialchars() function (which I was under the impression should encode them in HTML format for such characters, like: &). so as an example, if someone enters Me & you then it will be displayed as Me you.

In data encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded `&` means "Start of new key=value pair" and `+` means "A space". You need to [`urlencode($data)`](http://php.net/urlencode).

Comment: You're correct about urlencoding, but that shouldn't be an issue for `POST` data... right?

Comment: @davethegr8 — POST data is usually encoded as application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, that uses the same format as urls.

Comment: So would I, in the end, put `urlencode(htmlspecialchars($data,ENT_QUOTES));` for all fields that might contain any of these characters?

Comment: No! Don't apply escaping of data willy nilly. It is a precision tool. `urlencode` data *immediately* before sticking it in a URI or POST data. `htmlspecialchars` data *immediately* before sticking it in HTML. `mysql_real_escape_string` data *immediately* before sticking it in MySQL (except you should really be using bound parameters for that instead).

Comment: Thanks very much! I will also look into bound parameters once I get all of this sorted out. Always looking for better methods!

Comment: Regarding posting & directly, it's not affecting the data in any way as far as I can tell. I made a quick test with 3 inputs in a form, named val1, 2, and 3 in order. Then I set typed `Second&extra=1` into the second input, and then submitted the form. I had `if(!empty($_POST)) { print_r($_POST); }` on the same page, and when the form was submitted, the data looked like this: `Array ( [val1] => First [val2] => Second&extra=1 [val3] => Third )`. So, I think we must be referring to different things.

Comment: That isn't directly, that is allowing the browser to encode the form data for you.

Comment: I'm actually submitting to POST using Ajax, so I'm having trouble implementing the urlencode(). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2):

First, it helps to properly contain HTML attributes, like so:

```
<input type="text" value="Hello there I'm Jon" />
```

I'm using double quotes, notice the trailing quote on the value, which your original didn't have. If you then wrap the value in [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) you'll be able to properly display/save `"` or any other value in your form.

While double quotes aren't strictly necessary in HTML5 (`'` will work just fine in most cases), they are at least encouraged. If you're using some variant of XHTML, they are required.

Comment: XHTML [doesn't care if you use double quotes or single quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue). I've never see anything encouraging double over single except convention.

Comment: The only reason I use single quotes for this is because I'm printing it from PHP, therefore it is easier to write single quotes than escape double quotes. But admittedly in this case it may solve my problem with the `'`.

Comment: Until you start dealing with data that includes a `"`.

Comment: @Quentin - I guess I've gotten used to the convention for the sake of consistency over the years, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

A lazy but fast way to do things here is use urlencode() on the contents of the fields before they are posted, and the urldecode() on the other side.

It's not the proper way, or the nice way ... but it works if you don't want to write some specific code to handle the cases.